# How can i make a pyramid loop of number but in reverse

Tags: algorithm, go

I encounter a problem when try to make a pyramid of number in reverse of golang

I already can make a pyramid of number with this code :

```
var (
        input, bil int
    )

    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    bil = 9
    for b := 1; b <= input; b++ {
        for c := input; c >= b; c-- { //spasi
            fmt.Print(" ")
        }
        for d := 1; d <= b; d++ { //bintang

            fmt.Print(bil)

            if bil == -1 {
                bil = 9
            }
            bil = bil - 1
        }
        fmt.Println()

    }
```

Input :

```
5
```

Output :

```
     9
    87
   654
  3210
 98765
```

How do I make a reverse one like this

input:

```
5
```

Output

```
    9
   78
  456
 0123
56789
```

Comment: Could you please rename the variables to english? That would help. I think you just need to make `bil` go from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the way you calculate the current number (`fmt.Print(bil-d)`)

```
func main() {
    var (
        input, bil int
    )

    fmt.Scanln(&input)
    bil = 9
    for b := 1; b <= input; b++ {
        for c := input; c >= b; c-- {
            fmt.Print(" ")
        }

        for d := b - 1; d >= 0; d-- {
            v := bil - d
            if v < 0 {
                v = v%10 + 10
            }
            fmt.Print(v)
        }
        bil -= b
        if bil < 0 {
            bil = bil%10 + 10
        }
        fmt.Println()

    }
}
```

Note that I also change the handling of boundary conditions.